# How to set the color of "placeholder" text?

Tags: css, html, colors

Is that possible to set the color of `placeholder` text ?

```
<textarea placeholder="Write your message here..."></textarea>
```

Comment: There's a very full (and much better) answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nobody likes the "refer to this answer" answers, but in this case it may help: [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Since it's only supported by a couple of browsers, you can try the jQuery placeholder plugin (assuming you can\are using jQuery). It allows you to style the placeholder text via CSS since it's really only a swap trick it does with focus events.

The plugin does not activate on browsers that support it, though, so you can have CSS that targets chrome\firefox and the jQuery plugin's CSS to catch the rest.

The plugin can be found here: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 28):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {  color: #999;}
```

Answer (score 6):

For giving placeholder a color just use these lines of code:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; }
::-moz-placeholder {color: red; }
:-ms-input-placeholder { color: red; } 
:-o-input-placeholder { color: red; }
```

Comment: Which browser is the `-o-input-placeholder` for?

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE probably the Opera browser

Answer (score 3):

```
#Try this:

input[type="text"],textarea[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:#f51;
}
input[type="text"],textarea[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    color:#f51;
}
input[type="text"],textarea[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    color:#f51;
}
input[type="text"],textarea[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color:#f51;
}

##Works very well for me.
```

Answer (score -2):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Altynbek92/3rw2z0zt/)

```css
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #f51;
}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #f51;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #f51;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #f51;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Value" />
```

Comment: Boo. You just took an answer that was written a 1.5 years previously and added the code snippet to it.

Answer (score -4):

For Firefox use:

```
 input:-moz-placeholder { color: #aaa; }
 textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #aaa;}
```

For all other browsers (Chrome, IE, Safari), just use:

```
 .placeholder { color: #aaa; }
```

Comment: `.placeholder { color: #aaa; }` will change the color of the text not the placeholder -1

Comment: That makes no sense @Deadpool. The original question asked about changing the color of the placeholder text, which this solution does.

Comment: `.placeholder` targets elements with a class `placeholder` e.g. `class="placeholder"` so the line `.placeholder { color: #aaa; }` will change the color of the text not the placeholder.

Comment: Gotcha.  And yeah, you are correct. I did implement this in the past, but I typed this (non)solution in directly without testing it.  Good catch @Deadpool.