# Changing the formatting of HTML placeholder element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a placeholder element for my search box input:

```
  <input id="searchBarTextbox" type="search" class="k-textbox" placeholder="Search For..." />
```

However, I want the placeholder text to be 'bolder', to look like the actual text that's written in the text box.

more detail on JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RYBrk/1/

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839270/how-to-set-the-color-of-placeholder-text

Comment: Though this question is specifically about bolding and not color, the essential question is the same (how to style a placeholder), and so is the essential answer (using certain browser-dependent selectors).

Answer (score 0):

css, font-weight:bold;

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: black;
      font-weight:bold;
    }
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBrk/3/)

Comment: Is this will run in Mozilla?